# Need help with evaluation of expression encountered while deriving *alternative proof of sin x expansion* and need help with verification of proof

Tags: limits, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

---

I request you to kindly help me to understand the point of conflict that I struck at while deriving an **alternative proof of Sin x expansion** (apart from Taylor series approach). I have mentioned the steps of proof and also the point of paradox below. I would like to apologize in advance, in case you find difficulty in understanding the proof and would be happy to clarify any confusion or ambiguity in the steps of proof.

Please find the derivation of alternative proof of $\sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {(-1)^k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ expansion, below.

---

---

[**Please refer to this diagram link for understanding Section 1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCNDO.png)
**Section 1**

First I will prove that 
**$\sin x = \lim _{dx\to 0}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} dx*\cos ndx $**

**Consider sector of circle “A6 O A0”**
**angle “A6 O A0” = x radian**.
**Arc “A6 A0” = $(1 Unit)*(x Radian) = x Unit$** (Arc length = radius * angle in radian)

Now let us divide **$\angle$ 'A6 O A0'** into N(= 6 in diagram) equal parts, with each part = dx. Diving the angle will also divide arc "A6 A0" in N equal parts

**Consider length “A6 B6”**
$\sin x$ = **“A6 B6” = “A6 C6” + “A5 C5” + “A4 C4” + “A3 C3” + “A2 C2” + “A1 C1” -- equation 1**

We know that
**“A6 A5” = “A5 A4” = “A4 A3” = “A3 A2” = “A2 A1” = “A1 A0” = dx unit   -- equation 2**

**Let us consider example of right angle Triangle “O A4 B4”**
->**Angle “B4 O A4” = 4dx radian**
->Then we can say that angle **“C4 A4 A3” = 4dx radian** as well (because line “O A4” perpendicular to “A4 A3”)
->Hence length **“A4 C4” = “A4 A3”*$\cos 4dx = dx*\cos 4dx$** (“A4 A3” = dx unit, **from equation 2**)

**Base on above example, we can say the following**
“A6 C6” = $dx*\cos 6dx$,  “A5 C5” = $dx*\cos 5dx$,
“A4 C4” = $dx*\cos 4dx$,  “A3 C3” = $dx*\cos 3dx$,
“A2 C2” = $dx*\cos 2dx$,  “A1 C1” = $dx*\cos 1dx$   -- equation 3

Hence,
$sin x = dx*\cos 6dx + dx*\cos 5dx + dx*\cos 4dx + dx*\cos 3dx + dx*\cos 2dx + dx*\cos 1dx$, **From equation 1 and 2 and as per diagram where number of division, N = 6 )**

Since in diagram, I have divided angle x into N=6 parts to make it easy to understand.
But actually, **angle “A6 O A0” = x radian** should be divided into N equal parts such that following conditions should hold
$\lim _{N\to \infty }$
$\lim _{dx\to 0 }$
x radian $= N * dx$

Based on this
$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left(dx*\cos 1dx + dx*\cos 2dx + dx*\cos 3dx + dx*\cos 4dx + dx*\cos 5dx + dx*\cos 6dx + dx*\cos 7dx + \cdots + dx*\cos Ndx\right)$

Or

**$\sin x = \lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\sum^{N}_{n=1} dx*\cos ndx $**
**Hence Section 1 Proved**

---

---

**Section 2**

**In this section, I will further breakdown, transform and restructure equation $\sin x = \lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\sum^{N}_{n=1} dx*\cos ndx $, in an attempt to achieve the desired result of Taylor's series expansion of Sin x**

We know that,   ([Refer Link for more details on this formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/))
$\cos n\theta = \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant n}(-1)^r\binom{n}{2r}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{n-2r}{\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2r}}$

if $\theta = \lim _{dx\to 0} dx$, then above formula will become,
$\cos ndx = \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant n}(-1)^r\binom{n}{2r}dx^{2r}$  **-- equation 4**,
   because, $\lim _{dx\to 0} \cos dx = 1$  and $\lim _{dx\to 0} \frac{\sin dx}{dx} = 1$

**In Section 1**, we have already proved that
$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left(dx*\cos 1dx + dx*\cos 2dx + dx*\cos 3dx + dx*\cos 4dx + dx*\cos 5dx + dx*\cos 6dx + dx*\cos 7dx + \cdots + dx*\cos Ndx\right)$

**Using equation 4**, we will get

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant 1}(-1)^r\binom{1}{2r}dx^{2r} + \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant 2}(-1)^r\binom{2}{2r}dx^{2r} + \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant 3}(-1)^r\binom{3}{2r}dx^{2r} + \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant 4}(-1)^r\binom{4}{2r}dx^{2r} + \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant 5}(-1)^r\binom{5}{2r}dx^{2r} + \cdots + \sum_{r=0}^{2r \leqslant N}(-1)^r\binom{N}{2r}dx^{2r}\right)*dx$

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left({\Bigl [\binom{1}{0}dx^0\Bigr]}+{\Bigl[\binom{2}{0}dx^0-\binom{2}{2}dx^2\Bigr]}+{\Bigl[\binom{3}{0}dx^0-\binom{3}{2}dx^2\Bigr]}+{\Bigl[\binom{4}{0}dx^0-\binom{4}{2}dx^2+\binom{4}{4}dx^4\Bigr]}+{\Bigl[\binom{5}{0}dx^0-\binom{5}{2}dx^2+\binom{5}{4}dx^4\Bigr]}+\cdots+{\Bigl[\binom{m}{0}dx^0-\binom{m}{2}dx^2+\binom{m}{4}dx^4+\cdots\Bigr]} \right)*dx$

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left(-{\binom{0}{0}dx^0}+{\sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{0}{2}}\binom{n}{0}dx^0}+{\sum_{n=2}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{2}{2}}\binom{n}{2}dx^2}+{\sum_{n=4}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{4}{2}}\binom{n}{4}dx^4}+{\sum_{n=6}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{6}{2}}\binom{n}{6}dx^6}+\cdots+{\sum_{n=(m-1)}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{(m-1)}{2}}\binom{n}{m-1}{dx^\left(m-1\right)}}+\cdots+{\sum_{n=(N-2)}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{(N-2)}{2}}\binom{n}{N-2}{dx^\left(N-2\right)}}+{\sum_{n=N}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{N}{2}}\binom{n}{N}{dx^N}}\right)*dx$

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left(-{\binom{0}{0}dx^1}+{\sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{0}{2}}\binom{n}{0}dx^1}+{\sum_{n=2}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{2}{2}}\binom{n}{2}dx^3}+{\sum_{n=4}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{4}{2}}\binom{n}{4}dx^5}+{\sum_{n=6}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{6}{2}}\binom{n}{6}dx^7}+\cdots+{\sum_{n=(m-1)}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{(m-1)}{2}}\binom{n}{m-1}{dx^m}}+\cdots+{\sum_{n=(N-2)}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{(N-2)}{2}}\binom{n}{N-2}{dx^\left(N-1\right)}}+{\sum_{n=N}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{N}{2}}\binom{n}{N}{dx^\left(N+1\right)}}\right)$

**In above equation we can ignore 1st term $-{\binom{0}{0}dx^1}$ because $\lim _{dx\to 0 }$**

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\lim _{dx\to 0}\left({\sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{0}{2}}\binom{n}{0}dx^1}+{\sum_{n=2}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{2}{2}}\binom{n}{2}dx^3}+{\sum_{n=4}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{4}{2}}\binom{n}{4}dx^5}+{\sum_{n=6}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{6}{2}}\binom{n}{6}dx^7}+\cdots+{\sum_{n=(m-1)}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{(m-1)}{2}}\binom{n}{m-1}{dx^m}}+\cdots+{\sum_{n=(N-2)}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{(N-2)}{2}}\binom{n}{N-2}{dx^\left(N-1\right)}}+{\sum_{n=N}^{N}(-1)^{\frac{N}{2}}\binom{n}{N}{dx^\left(N+1\right)}}\right)$

**we know that x $= N * dx$, then after re-writing above equation, we will get**

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\left((-1)^0\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{n}{0}}{N^1}x^1+(-1)^1\frac{\sum_{n=2}^{N}\binom{n}{2}}{N^3}x^3+(-1)^2\frac{\sum_{n=4}^{N}\binom{n}{4}}{N^5}x^5+(-1)^3\frac{\sum_{n=6}^{N}\binom{n}{6}}{N^7}x^7+\cdots+(-1)^k\frac{\sum_{n=2k}^{N}\binom{n}{2k}}{N^\left(2k+1\right)}{x^\left(2k+1\right)}+\cdots+(-1)^{\frac{(N-2)}{2}}\frac{\sum_{n=(N-2)}^{N}\binom{n}{N-2}}{N^\left(N-1\right)}{x^\left(N-1\right)}+(-1)^{\frac{N}{2}}\frac{\sum_{n=N}^{N}\binom{n}{N}}{N^\left(N+1\right)}{x^\left(N+1\right)}\right)$

Let us consider the **kth term** in above sequence

**kth term** $=(-1)^k\frac{\sum_{n=2k}^{N}\binom{n}{2k}}{N^\left(2k+1\right)}{x^\left(2k+1\right)}$

**Kth term can be re-written as**

**kth term** $=(-1)^k\frac{1}{N^\left(2k+1\right)}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-2k)}\frac{(2k+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^\left(2k+1\right)}{2k!}$

$\sin x$ = $\lim _{N\to \infty }\left(
(-1)^0\frac{1}{N^1}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{n!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^1}{0!}+
(-1)^1\frac{1}{N^3}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-2)}\frac{(2+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^3}{2!}+
(-1)^2\frac{1}{N^5}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-4)}\frac{(4+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^5}{4!}+
(-1)^3\frac{1}{N^7}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-6)}\frac{(6+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^7}{6!}+
\cdots+
(-1)^k\frac{1}{N^\left(2k+1\right)}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-2k)}\frac{(2k+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^\left(2k+1\right)}{2k!}+
\cdots+
(-1)^{\frac{(N-2)}{2}}\frac{1}{N^\left(N-1\right)}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{2}\frac{(N-2+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^\left(N-1\right)}{(N-2)!}+
(-1)^{\frac{N}{2}}\frac{1}{N^\left(N+1\right)}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{0}\frac{(N+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\frac{x^\left(N+1\right)}{N!}\right)$

---

---

**Section 3 - Paradox**

**Let**  $P(k) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \Biggl [\frac{1}{N^\left(2k+1\right)}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-2k)}\frac{(2k+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\Biggr]$

**Then**
$\sin x$ = $
(-1)^0P(0)\frac{x^1}{0!}+
(-1)^1P(1)\frac{x^3}{2!}+
(-1)^2P(2)\frac{x^5}{4!}+
(-1)^3P(3)\frac{x^7}{6!}+
\cdots+
(-1)^kP(k)\frac{x^\left(2k+1\right)}{2k!}+
\cdots\cdots\infty$  -- **Equation 5**
$\sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {(-1)^k}P(k)\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k!}$

**As per Taylor's Series expansion**
$\sin x$ = $
(-1)^0\frac{x^1}{1!}+
(-1)^1\frac{x^3}{3!}+
(-1)^2\frac{x^5}{5!}+
(-1)^3\frac{x^7}{7!}+
\cdots+
(-1)^k\frac{x^\left(2k+1\right)}{2k+1!}+
\cdots\cdots\infty$

$\sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {(-1)^k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$

**Paradox** :- I need to evaluate expression P(k) for all k, $0 \leqslant k \leqslant \infty$
Ideally, P(k) should be equal to  $ \frac{1}{2k+1} $ to get the result of this alternative proof to be equal to actual Taylor's Series expansion of Sin x. But when I attempt to evaluate P(k) (I may be wrong in evaluating it), I am getting P(k) equal to ***1*** irrespective of value of k. (I can provide steps on how I am attempting to evaluate P(k), if needed)

(Kindly Note :- I used below formula to evaluate P(k). I found it in Wikipedia for gamma function, in definition section.  [**Click here to open Wikipedia link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function))

$\lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {n!\;(n+1)^{m}}{(n+m)!}}=1$

Kindly provide your suggestions !

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are going to have very little luck finding people willing to try to decipher that. As you've already found, your limit really does converge to $1$ for all $m$. So the problem has to be in your derivation that made you think this limit needed some other value. But trying to track down the mistake you made is just too hard to see. You'll have to write it up much more neatly. Since you obviously can do some mathjax, writing it up in that would be the best. Try to leave out any unnecessary details.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for your precious feedback. I will try to write down the proof using mathjax as soon as possible.

Comment: Your formula in section 1 is basically $$\sin x=\int_{0}^{x}\cos t\, dt=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x} {n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{ix}{n}\right)$$ and you should start from here. The formula which you have written does not appear to make sense.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh - Thanks for your feedback. That's correct. But still we should be able to use summation formula instead of integration counterpart. If we further evaluate this summation formula correctly in mathematical sense then we can get new insights and results. For, e.g, If my derivation is mathematically correct then it gave raise to below new result, which might not have existed before.
                                         
$\lim_{N\to \infty} \Biggl [\frac{1}{N^\left(m+1\right)}\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{(N-m)}\frac{(m+n)!}{n!}\Biggr)\Biggr] = \frac{1}{m+1}$

Comment: @PaulSinclair - I have written down the derivation here. I hope, now it should be easy to understand. Thanks for your feedback again.